# NextJS Router routeChangeComplete is not triggered always

Tags: next.js

I am using NextJS `version "12.1.0"` and am facing one very interesting bug/issue.

I am using `Router` events in order to track pageviews for Google Analytics.

My issue is that, router.events.on('routeChangeComplete',...) `routeChangeComplete` is triggered for some pages, and not for others.
example:

/posts is not triggering the event (code at pages/posts.tsx)

/data is triggering the event (code at pages/data.tsx)

Both the react components for the pages above are similar... normal nextjs pages

Both do trigger this line `console.log('registering router events');` so the useEffect of course is executed after _app.tsx renders and register the router events.
Additionally, the event listener is not removed because the line `remove router event...` is not output in the console.

Seems like the issue is that router is not always triggering the event.

I have this code in my `_app.tsx`

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
// other imports and code

const MyApp = function ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) {
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('registering router events');
        const handleRouteChange = (url: string) => {
            console.log('dandy trout route change', url);
            tracker.pageview(url);
        };
        router.events.on('routeChangeStart', (evts) => {
            console.log('routeChangeStart', evts);
        });
        router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
        return () => {
            console.log('remove router event...');
            router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', handleRouteChange);
        };
    }, [router.events]);
```

tracker is just a wrapper for google analytics.

In some urls `routeChangeComplete` is called, in others not (for the first page load)
After the initial load, on next page visiting the routeChangeComplete is called always and works fine.

I double checked my page where the event is not trigered and is not using anything weird on unusual. I don't understand why is acting differently for different urls

Comment: `routeChangeComplete` (and all the other router events) only gets triggered on client-side page transitions (generated by `next/router`). It doesn't get triggered on initial page loads (no matter what the page's path is).

Comment: That is very interesting because that is getting triggered in most of my pages aside 1. As wrote in the post, in other pages routeChangeComplete is executed on first page load...

Comment: How do you explain such a fact ? I open for example `/data` and that event is triggered. I open `/posts` the event is not triggered...

Comment: Hard to tell without a [mre].